# PowerPoint presentations including Latex both under Windows and Mac OS

Tags: online-resource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a presentation that includes math symbols?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-to-make-a-presentation-that-includes-math-symbols)

I have been using TeX4PPT for PowerPoint under Windows for a few years to include matematical formulas in PP presentations. Recently, I got a Mac notebook and I would like to use my PP presentations both under Windows as well as under Mac OS X. However, I cannot find a program that would allow me to use LaTeX generating formulas in PP under both operating systems (so I could use my  presentations freely on both OS). Any ideas?

Comment: You should try [beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29), it is an awesome tool for presentation. Furthermore there are so many available [resources](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) online.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac Os only, you can use [Keynote](http://www.apple.com/iwork/keynote/) and [Latexit](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php), as explained in this question: [How to make a presentation that includes math symbols?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/301/102) I've been using this technique recently, and it's very nice!
However, as far as I know, you cannot show Keynote presentation on Windows. A possible solution could be to export them as PPT, but I've just tried, and it's not very nice, especially for the included formulas. You can also export them as PDF, in which case it's graphically nice, but you lose any animated transition.

Another solution could be to use Latexit to generate PDF, and to include the PDF directly in Powerpoint. If you use a white background, that can do the trick, since formulas will be exported with a white background (but maybe it's possible to set it up, I've never tried with Powerpoint to be honest, so maybe you can import SVG format directly in Powerpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to work directly in tex (that is, via [Beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29)) and get a cross-platform presentations. Although, if you want to do presentation animations and sophisticated tricks, this is inferior to PPT/Keynote.

Comment: [citation needed]